# C++ MFC How to Draw Alpha transparent Rectangle

Tags: c++, mfc, paint

in a C++ MFC application. using the **dc**  of ( `CPaintDC dc(this);` )

How do i draw a rectangle ( `LPRECT` ) with an alpha transparency  that i can adjust.?

**Following is an example c# code which i need to convert into C++**

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)  
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Color color = Color.FromArgb(75,Color.Red); //sets color Red with 75% alpha transparency

    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(100,100,400,400);
    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(color), rectangle); //draws the rectangle with the color set.
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to look into GDI+.  Its a bit of a faff but you can create a "Graphics" object as follows:

```
Gdiplus::Graphics g( dc.GetSafeHdc() );
Gdiplus::Color color( 192, 255, 0, 0 );

Gdiplus::Rect rectangle( 100, 100, 400, 400 );
Gdiplus::SolidBrush solidBrush( color );
g.FillRectangle( &solidBrush, rectangle );
```

Don't forget to do

```
#include <gdiplus.h>
```

and to call

```
 GdiplusStartup(...);
```

somewhere :)

You'll notice it's pretty damned similar to your C# code ;)

Its worth noting that the 75 you put in your `FromArgb` code doesn't set 75% alpha it actually sets 75/255 alpha or ~29% alpha.

Comment: If i invoke GdiplusStartup(); is it must that i should invoke GdiplusShutdown ?

I think i must. and if i must, should it be within the Paint Event?

Comment: GdiplusStartup should be invoked once usally from the InitInstance function of your MFC app.  GdiplusShutdown should, then, be called once as your application exits.

Answer (score 3):

GDI (and thus MFC) has no decent support for drawing with an alpha.  But GDI+ is available in C++ code as well.  Use `#include <gdiplus.h>` and initialize it with GdiplusStartup().  You can use the Graphics class, create one with its Graphics(HDC) constructor from your CPaintDC.  And use its FillRectangle() method.  The SDK docs [are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533799%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

```
int StartHoriz,StartVert,BarWidth,BarHeight; // rect start, width and height
StartHoriz=0;
StartVert=100;
width = 100;
height=120;
CDC* pCDC = GetDC();      // Get CDC pointer
CRect Rect(StartHoriz,StartVert,BarWidth,BarHeight);  //create rectangle dimensions
pCDC->Rectangle(Rect);   //draw rectangle
```